# How to handle different-case usernames in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having an issue with Firebase DB involving case sensitive keys. For example: I create a "Username" key for every new user that registers. I'm validating this "Username" value through regex and also checking if the value entered already exists in the database (checking username availability). My issue is that I just realized Firebase assumes different sentence case of the same value is a different value.

For example:

**"Username": john** and 
**"Username": John** are seen as two different/unique usernames

I was thinking taking the user's desired username input string and making it all caps (or all lowercase), creating uniformity in the database, but then it would kill the ability of having a mixed-case username. Is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: Use the uppercase username as the key. The value would be user information, including the user-specified username.

Comment: I typically add a secondary property for searching. Well.... I typically add a full-text search service. But if that isn't an option, I add `UsernameLowercase` or `UsernameIdiomatic` for searching.

Comment: So, isn't this what you want? For mixed case usernames, you do need Firebase to be case sensitive, don't you? Or do you want "John" and "john" to be the same key? In that case, your username is not case sensitive anymore, and you will lose ability of having mixed case username.

Looks like you want the user to be able to enter mixed cases, but the query not to be case sensitive. In that case I think `UsernameLowercase ` is the way to go as @FrankvanPuffelen mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using firebase. The solution was create a new property with lowercase for "searchable" fields on my system. Also I remove the accents from words on this property.